# How do I get back all my lost programs after I refreshed my Windows PC?

Tags: windows

I tried to refresh my PC. As explained in the options, when I refresh, I wouldn't lose any files.

But after I refreshed my PC, I lost every Microsoft program (Office, PowerPoint, etc.) and even Firefox, Google Chrome and some music or photo programs all disappeared. And my PC just offered me to buy new Microsoft office 2010.

I have no idea how to recover my previous programs.

Comment: Why not restore the backup you made before you did something new and possibly destructive?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to say this, but you misunderstood what "refresh" does.  It keeps your user files and data, however, underlying *Windows is essentially returned to however it was shipped to you* (i.e. registry reverted, installed programs gone, etc.).

Assuming it came to you with any of that on it, you should be able to find the files on your recovery partition.

> [Windows 8 Refresh: A great feature, if you know the limitations](http://www.infoworld.com/t/microsoft-windows/windows-8-refresh-great-feature-if-you-know-the-limitations-190100)
>
> Refresh, you may recall, is the Windows 8 revitalization procedure that preserves the user's data and settings but re-installs Windows underneath. (Reset is the other option, which wipes out the PC and returns it to the same state it was in when you bought it.) Microsoft advises that Windows 8 customers run a Refresh under the same circumstances that Windows 7 users might run a System Restore -- that is, when your system suddenly falls over or starts behaving absurdly.

That means that unless you had backed any of that up (or did a system restore point) beforehand, you'll need to start from scratch essentially.  Though, your settings files are probably still valid under your user folder.  That may mitigate some of the pain...

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem but was lucky enough to try searching in the "Windows.old" folder and found all of my lost files. It's a lot of work to copy all of those back, but hey at least it's something.

You can check it at the Microsoft site
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-files-upgrade-windows-old